# how to disable email confirmation in gitlab in private network

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails, gitlab

Recently I installed the gitlab for my LAN. When my users are trying to create their accounts they are getting email confirmation message. Now my question is I want to disable whole email confirmation feature and everything. For that what file i have to configure in the gitlab configuration files how to do this? which options i have to change i am very poor in ruby please explain in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i needed recently to patch gitlab for skipping confirmation for LDAP users. I do not consider   this as a good patch but it works.

vim /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/api/users.rb:

```
  post do
    authenticated_as_admin!
    ...
                                # <patch:     
    if attrs[:extern_uid]       # skip confirmation for LDAP users
       user.skip_confirmation!  #
    end                         # >

    if user.save
      present user, with: Entities::UserFull
    else
```

Restart is obviously required ( gitlab-ctl restart )

Based on answer in google group:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlabhq/ctf8x0xpOOE

Answer (score 3):

Since version `7.9.0` E-Mail confirmation can be skipped by including a `confirm` parameter into your JSON. For example, if you want to create a user *Jenkins* without email confirmation you do a `POST` with the following payload against your local gitlab API:

```
POST /api/v3/users?private_token=<administrator token>
{
 "email" : "jenkins@test.com",
 "password" : "123456",
 "name" : "Jenkins CI Server",
 "username" : "jenkins",
 "confirm" : "no"
}
```

Parameters `email`, `password`, `name` and `username` are mandatory. The change was introduced with this [commit](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/5f682094d9b7c985ad62ebe29664bb6fe87b54be). As you might see, the confirm parameter may also be one of `false`, `0` and `f` to disable email confirmation.

Comment: the <administrator token> can be found at /profile/account